# Filter phyloseq sequence table

Tags: r, phyloseq

I have phyloseq object where sequence table were builded by using the function mergeSequenceTables from DADA2 package, to merge ten sequence tables from different runs.
The sample_data consist of two columns 1)containing sample names same as sequence table column names and 2)study name from which samples comes from.

Using this information I want to subset sequences that have  average relative abundance > 0.1% at least in 3 studies.

I tried this but it doesn't consider information about studies.

```
prevalenceDF = data.frame(Prevalence = colSums(otu_table(ps.trans) > 0),
                      TotalAbundance = colSums(otu_table(ps.trans)),
                      tax_table(ps.trans)
)

summary_prevalence <- plyr::ddply(prevalenceDF, "Genus", function(df){ data.frame(mean_prevalence = mean(df$Prevalence),
             totalAbundance = sum(df$TotalAbundance, na.rm = T), stringsAsFactors = F) })


keepPhyla <- summary_prevalence$Phylum[summary_prevalence$totalAbundance/sum(summary_prevalence$totalAbundance)
>= 0.001] 
ps.1 = subset_taxa(ps, Phylum %in% keepPhyla)
```

Does anyone have any pointers haw can I count how many studies containing each genera and add as column to prevalenceDF data frame or other way to do filtering?